# How to correctly show WeChat profile from website?

Tags: html, wechat

I am searching for a best way to show WeChat profile in app after user click on link on some website.
I found some solution here but it's not working for me.
For example I tried these URIs:

```
<a href="weixin://dl/chat?{wechatId}">link</a>
```

Or in href attribute:

```
weixin://contacts/profile/{wechatId}
```

It's not working for me. After I click on this, WeChat app is opened and immediately closed. Or it show me not found error on Tips tab..

Is there some way to do it?

Comment: Are you are developing WeChat Official Account or Website Application? Since  your Website application needs to register on Open Platform in order to use WeChat user profile to login and access profile.

Comment: Hi @DylanL. Thank you for your reply. It's only website which has social buttons (like facebook, instagram, linkedIn), and WeChat too. I would like to open business profile on WeChat app when I click on WeChat button .. it's only redirect (like when you click on facebook social icon and you are redirected to specific facebook page), not WeChat login on my website.

Answer (score 0):

I think WeChat has not public profile webpage like facebook for now, you can only access other people's profile in the WeChat app by scanning a QR code or search by WeChat id/phone number.  The code snippets that you mentioned above has been discarded by WeChat Official(But you may still can see it in some old official documentations).

If you still want to achieve this function, I recommend you just post your QR code in your webpage.

However, some people using the `weixin://` as a bug to link WeChat to others apps. You still can generate a tickets like `weixin://dl/business/?ticket=***`. The `***` contains your wechatid and is encrypted by some specific algorithms, which is not opened by WeChat official. And also, buying some third-part server tickets like [this](https://github.com/wxbug-cn/ticket) to get the jump link works for now but not stable.